# Running a RegEx on an ITextViewLine (Visual Studio Extension)

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I am looking to run a RegEx search to find all occurrences of certain keywords in the Editor Window and then draw some adornments and add some tags to them.

Is there any way to run a RegEx on an `ITextViewLine`.

This is how my calling function looks:

```
private void OnLayoutChanged(object sender, TextViewLayoutChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ITextViewLine line in e.NewOrReformattedLines)
    {
        this.CreateVisuals(line);
    }
}

private void CreateVisuals(ITextViewLine line)
{
    IWpfTextViewLineCollection textViewLines = _wpfTextView.TextViewLines;
    // Run RegEx match here and do some stuff for all matches
}
```

As suggested by [@stribizhev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/stribizhev) I tried using `FormattedSpan` as follows:

```
private void CreateVisuals(ITextViewLine line)
{
    var textViewLines = _wpfTextView.TextViewLines;
    var snapshot = textViewLines.FormattedSpan;
    var text = snapshot.ToString();
    var todoRegex = new Regex(@"\/\/\s*TODO\b");
    var match = todoRegex.Match(text);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        int matchStart = line.Start.Position + match.Index;
        var span = new SnapshotSpan(_wpfTextView.TextSnapshot, Span.FromBounds(matchStart, matchStart + match.Length));
        DrawAdornment(textViewLines, span);
    }
}
```

But this causes a `NullReference` at the call to DrawAdornment telling me that `span` is unset.
And moreover by putting breakpoints on all lines in the `CreateVisuals` function I saw that the highlighting only starts when the line containing the `TODO` scrolls out of view or becomes the first line in the viewport.

The input I tried was:

```
using System;
public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        // TODO: It's a good thing to have todos
    }
}
```

The code is able to put adornments sometimes but they are shifted slightly to the right and appear on three different lines.

Comment: Did you check the `FormattedSpan` property?

Comment: @stribizhev I'll try it out. Thanks.

Comment: If you just do not need to set any new values to it, it seems you can use `Regex.Matches(textViewLines.FormattedSpan.Span, @"REGEX_HERE")` and get your matches.

Comment: @stribizhev I did try `FormattedSpan` but had some issues. See the new information.

Comment: Well thanks @stribizhev. I finally was able to fix the issues. Seems like `FormattedSpan` has method `.Snapshot.GetText()` which gives a plain string and we can run RegEx easily on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally got it to work. There are two ways to do it.

**My way (easier)**:

```
private void CreateVisuals()
    {
        var textViewLines = _wpfTextView.TextViewLines;
        var text = textViewLines.FormattedSpan.Snapshot.GetText();
        var todoRegex = new Regex(@"\/\/\s*TODO\b");
        var match = todoRegex.Match(text);
        while (match.Success)
        {
            var matchStart = match.Index;
            var span = new SnapshotSpan(_wpfTextView.TextSnapshot, Span.FromBounds(matchStart, matchStart + match.Length));
            DrawAdornment(textViewLines, span);
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }
```

**The tough(er) way:** (From [this article](http://chrisparnin.github.io/articles/2013/09/using-tagging-and-adornments-for-better-todos-in-visual-studio/))

```
/// <summary>
/// This will get the text of the ITextView line as it appears in the actual user editable 
/// document. 
/// jared parson: https://gist.github.com/4320643
/// </summary>
public static bool TryGetText(IWpfTextView textView, ITextViewLine textViewLine, out string text)
{
    var extent = textViewLine.Extent;
    var bufferGraph = textView.BufferGraph;
    try
    {
        var collection = bufferGraph.MapDownToSnapshot(extent, SpanTrackingMode.EdgeInclusive, textView.TextSnapshot);
        var span = new SnapshotSpan(collection[0].Start, collection[collection.Count - 1].End);
        //text = span.ToString();
        text = span.GetText();
        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        text = null;
        return false;
    }
}

Regex todoLineRegex = new Regex(@"\/\/\s*TODO\b");

private void CreateVisuals(ITextViewLine line)
{
    IWpfTextViewLineCollection textViewLines = _view.TextViewLines;
    string text = null;
    if (TryGetText(_view, line, out text))
    {
        var match = todoLineRegex.Match(text);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            int matchStart = line.Start.Position + span.Index;
            var span = new SnapshotSpan(_view.TextSnapshot, Span.FromBounds(matchStart, matchStart + match.Length));
            DrawAdornment(textViewLines, span);
        }
    }
}
```